# MonoTouch Adding Encryption in the getter/setter

Tags: sqlite, encryption, xamarin.ios

I am using Sqlite database in my app with RijndaelManaged Encryption. Encryption works fine. The problem is how do i add encryption/decryption to my object class. Below is a class

```
 public class MTBL_USER
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public string LoginID { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to add encryption/decryption logic for LoginID and Password in getter and setter. something like

```
    public string LoginID
    {
        get { 
            EncryptDecryptController decrypt = new EncryptDecryptController ();
            return decrypt.Decrypt(LoginID); 
        }
        set { 
            EncryptDecryptController encrypt = new EncryptDecryptController ();
            LoginID = encrypt.Encrypt (value); 
        }
    }
```

This won't work. What is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has StackOverflow in it, it happens if you set LoginID from LoginID's set method.
Try adding a private field that stores the data.

private string _encryptedLoginID = null;

```
public string LoginID{
  get{ return (new EncruptDecryptController()).Decrypt(_encryptedLoginID);}
  set{ _encryptedLoginID = (new EncruptDecryptController()).Encrypt(value);}
}
```

Notice that a database/json/xml serializer will still see the decrypted value when they ask for it, so this is probably not going to do the trick for you.

Continue with this code and mark the LoginID property as ignored for your method of serialization; mark it internal if you can. For example:

```
[DataMemberIgnore]
[JsonIgnore]
[XmlIgnore]
public string LoginID{...}
```

Then add another property that communicates `_encryptedLoginID` directly

```
public string EncryptedLoginID {
  get {return _encryptedLoginID;} 
  set {_encryptedLoginID=value;}
}
```

You can also rename `LoginID` to CleartextLoginID and `EncryptedLoginID` to LoginID if you want to keep things with less attributes.

Keep in mind that "encryption" is a term lightly tossed around without ever mentioning a very important part of crypto-security: key management. If your key is easy to recover from your code or config files this entire exercise is pointless. You'd be surprised how easy it is some times to get through such defenses. If you're only slowing your attacker down by a few hours you might as well just B64-encode :). Make sure that's not the case and that your key is properly protected by whatever the OS has to offer - don't store it in config files or code.